# How to kill svchost.exe process permanently in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, localhost

I have AWS we ec2 server, where the process `svchost.exe` is consuming heavy memory.
I would like to kill the process permanently. How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

`svchost.exe` is a *generic* [service host](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-svchost-exe#1TC=windows-7) process. Identify the actual hosted service that consumes the memory and take appropriate action depending on the service in question.

> To view which services are currently running under svchost.exe
>
> - Open Task Manager by right-clicking the taskbar, and then clicking Start Task Manager.
> - Click the Processes tab.
> - Click Show processes from all users.  Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
> - Right-click an instance of svchost.exe, and then click Go to Service(s). The services associated with the process are highlighted on the Services tab.

Answer (score 1):

1. Type 'resource monitor' in search box of start menu.
2. Go under CPU tab.
3. Then expand processes.
4. There you see lots of processes,check all svchost.exe processes.
5. Then expand services,now it filtered by above checked processes.
6. Now you have to stop all services (one by one) in services section by righting then and select stop service.

That all we can try to stop svchost.exe.

Hope it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps and stop this service pemanately
1.Windows+R
2.type services.msc
3.search superfetch in list
4.click it stop
5.right click and go to settings
5.make it disabled instead of automatic
Done reboot.